# Trouble printing out character (♭ U+266D) on console using wprintf

Tags: c++, c, unicode, wchar

I want to print the musical flat symbol: `♭` (U+266D) on a console. I use `wchar_t` and `wprintf()` to do that, but it always prints out `?` instead of `♭`. I tried `setmode()` and `setlocale()` as well, as you can see down in the code, but neither of them was successful.

```
int main(){
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");

    wprintf(L"\u226d");
}
```

Comment: Does the font used in the console support that character?

Comment: Did you have the locale `en_US.UTF-8` installed? Locale names changes between OS and versions of the same OS. Note: UTF-8 is different encoding of O_U16TEXT. So you are using incompatible encodings. Is your console UTF-8 console? It is set to use UTF-8 characters? What about the font? Note: this question is marked duplicate, but if you are not using Windows, you may edit your question and ask to reopen it.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Thank you for taking the time and helping me out. This question was marked correctly as a duplicate. I'm still trying to figure out how to change my font to one who supports the flat symbol. I didn't install the local 'en_US.UTF-8', if that is something, you have to install manually.